# Unable to print variables in Python 3

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, variables

Basically i am trying to print a variable with a string assigned to it.
     `s="This is the string`".
And i am trying to print this variable like this :

```
print("text is here : %s") %(s)
```

but it gives me following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-10-10e38e220691>", line 2
print 'text is here: %s' %(s)
                                                ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `print("text is here : %s" %s)`

Comment: it worked !! Thank You For helping !!